# Binary Search Tree in Java using mm/dd/yyyy dates with associated names

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, date

I'm having an issue with BST that can't seem to figure out.
I am to output get, min, max, floor, ceiling, rank, iterator using the DOB in my project.
I am currently hung up on the Dates being unaccepted due to integer number being too large.

```
public class StringBinaryTreeSample {

node root;

public void addNode(int key, String name) {

    // Create a new Node and initialize it

    node newNode = new node(key, name);

// If there is no root this becomes root

    if (root == null) {

        root = newNode;

    } else {

        // Set root as the Node we will start
        // with as we traverse the tree

    node focusNode = root;

        // Future parent for our new Node

    node parent;

        while (true) {

            // root is the top parent so we start
            // there

            parent = focusNode;

            // Check if the new node should go on
            // the left side of the parent node

            if (key <= focusNode.key) {

                // Switch focus to the left child

                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

                // If the left child has no children

                if (focusNode == null) {

                    // then place the new node on the left of it

                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    return; // All Done

                }

            } else { // If we get here put the node on the right

                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

                // If the right child has no children

                if (focusNode == null) {

                    // then place the new node on the right of it

                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    return; // All Done

                }

            }

        }
    }

}

// All nodes are visited in ascending order
// Recursion is used to go to one node and
// then go to its child nodes and so forth

  public void inOrderTraverseTree(node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {

        // Traverse the left node

        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);

        // Visit the currently focused on node

        System.out.println(focusNode);

        // Traverse the right node

        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);

    }

}


public node findNode(int key) {

    // Start at the top of the tree

    node focusNode = root;

    // While we haven't found the Node
    // keep looking

    while (focusNode.key != key) {

        // If we should search to the left

        if (key == focusNode.key) {

            // Shift the focus Node to the left child

            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

        } else {

            // Shift the focus Node to the right child

            focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

        }

        // The node wasn't found

        if (focusNode == null)
            return null;

    }

    return focusNode;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

StringBinaryTreeSample theTree = new StringBinaryTreeSample();

    theTree.addNode("8/15/1998", "Mujib");

    theTree.addNode("5/13/2005", "Zia");

    theTree.addNode("1/13/1952", "Freedom");

    theTree.addNode("2/12/1990", "Victory");

    theTree.addNode("3/2/1985", "Molly");

    theTree.addNode("5/1/2010", "Asad");

    theTree.addNode("11/23/1983", "Genny");

    theTree.addNode("6/14/1979", "Independent");

    // Different ways to traverse binary trees

    // theTree.inOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);

    // theTree.preorderTraverseTree(theTree.root);

    // theTree.postOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);

    // Find the node with key 75
    theTree.inOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
    System.out.println("11/23/1983");

    System.out.println(theTree.findNode(1));

}


public String toString() {

    return name + " has the DOB " + key;

    /*
     * return name + " has the key " + key + "\nLeft Child: " + leftChild +
     * "\nRight Child: " + rightChild + "\n";
     */

}

public class node implements Comparable {

    int key;
    String name;

    node leftChild;
    node rightChild;


    node(int key, String name) {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
    }

    private int handleDOB(final node that){ 

        final String [] thisDOB = key.split("/");
        final String [] thatDOB = that.key.split("/");


        final int thisMonth = Integer.valueOf(thisDOB[0]);
        final int thisDay = Integer.valueOf(thisDOB[1]);
        final int thisYear = Integer.valueOf(thisDOB[2]);

        final int thatMonth = Integer.valueOf(thatDOB[0]);
        final int thatDay = Integer.valueOf(thatDOB[1]);
        final int thatYear = Integer.valueOf(thatDOB[2]);

        if (thisYear < thatYear) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (thisYear > thatYear) {
            return +1;
        }
        if (thisMonth < thatMonth) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (thisMonth > thatMonth) {
            return +1;
        }
        if (thisDay < thatDay) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (thisDay > thatDay) {
            return +1;
        }
        return 0;


    }
}




}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem more precisely and provide only the specific code?

Comment: please take the time and effort to format your code properly. **the amount of effort YOU put into your question is the amount of effort you might expect someone to put into an answer** in this case, that would be *not much*

Comment: `03/26/1971` is a mathematical expression; `"03/26/1971"` would be a `String` representation of a a Date.

Answer (score 1):

The first evident issue i see is this one:

```
theTree.addNode(08/15/1975, "Mujib");
```

That first parameter it's not a date in Java... you are performing a division with result equals to 0 since it's casted to int from it's original float value of 0.00027, use a Date object instead or an integer timestamp (maybe uglier but more practical?).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a date in Java:

```
08/15/1975
```

It is a numeric expression that attempts to divide `08` by `15`, then by `1975`.  If it did work, then integer division would yield `0`.

But the "integer too large" error occurs because prefixing an `int` literal with a `0` indicates to Java that you have an [*octal* literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-OctalNumeral), and only the digits 0-7 are legal for an octal number.

It is unclear how you expect a date to be implicitly converted to an `int`.

You may want to switch to using a `Calendar` object.  You can parse a string such a `"08/15/1975"` into a `Calendar` using a `SimpleDateFormat`.  If you're using Java 8, then you have the option of using `LocalDate`.

Comment: Ah okay, and i apologizing over the formatting. The teachers requirements and examples are extremely vague so i'm digging on the internet for hints to do this. I didn't realize it was accepting it as a division problem, that makes sense. i will look into the calendar, simpledateformat and see what i can come up with. Thank you guys.

Comment: i have looked into int convert to string but haven't found any sample code nor any information regarding how to apply it. i'v also attempted char but not sure how to apply it to the int. essentially i will have to customize it to read from a text file that will have unsorted data similar to "01/01/2001(MM/dd/yyyy, John, and similarly output the data same way 01/01/2001 (MM/dd/yyyy), John(with functions applied to data). and i'm just about stumped on how to get the search tree to read the DOB, any help is greatly appreciated (sample code would help to analyze if any available thanks.